# How to use albeit?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I've been learning English as a second language and I'm continually exploring and perusing articles constantly to improve my vocabulary. I stumbled across "albeit" and wanted to ensure that I understood the use of this word.

I know this question has been asked before, but I want to make sure this is the correct way of using albeit:

"..., despite the fact that he wasn't recognized as much, I consider him on a par with...", can you change it with "..., albeit he wasn't recognized as much, I consider him on a par with..." (taking into account that it can be changed to "..., although he wasn't recognized as much..." (note that it isn't the beginning of a sentence, there's a comma indicating that there's more behind).

Is it interchangeable like that? I researched online and it says it shouldn't be used at the start of a sentence but can be used in the middle of a sentence. I'm not sure if I can use it like this, though.

Comment: *albeit* is nearly synonymous with *although* but there are uses where swapping to "albeit" would be awkward. For example, *"You shouldn't, although you might want to"* would not read well as *"You shouldn't, albeit you might want to.*" You would also not want to start a sentence with *albeit*, as you point out. Generally *albeit* indicates that the sentence presents the reader with logical reasoning beyond what you would expect with using something like *even though* or *although*. Also, *albeit* allows for compact sentences since it's a short word itself: "Chic apartment, albeit flat."

Comment: It may not be the start of a sentence how you have it, but it appears that it **should** be the start of a sentence and your "sentence" is actually ungrammatical. It's probably a run-on sentence and the comma at the very start should be a full-stop. We actually need **all** the context here.